# Windows Phone: How to remove TimeSpanPicker highlight on press?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am using a `TimeSpanPicker` in my app. When I press it to select the time, the button background color will change to yellow.

```
for(int i=0;i< 3;i++)
{

   TimeSpanPicker tsp = new TimeSpanPicker();
   tsp.Value = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:00");
   tsp.Height=72;
   Instance.Listbox1.Elements.Add(tsp); // something like this
}
```

How do I change the Style of the Windows Phone `TimeSpanPicker` control?

Comment: Can you post some code? Is this a telerik tool? You need to provide more info.

Comment: I changed it, please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

After two days of searching, finally I found how to change the background of a TimeSpanPicker.

Step 1 :  Change Style of TimeSpanPicker in your xaml file. (in my case I wanted to change the background color to Transparent, so I set the value to Transparent)

```
        <Grid x:Name="grid">
            <Grid.Resources>
                 <Style x:Key="SampleStyle" TargetType="toolkit:TimeSpanPaicker">
                     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                     <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
                 </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
        </Grid>
```

Step 2: use the above style in code behind. You just need to set the style of a new TimeSpanPicker to the style on the top.

```
       TimeSpanPicker tsp = new TimeSpanPicker();
       tsp.Style = (System.Windows.Style)Resources["SampleStyle"];
```

That is how we can change different features of our TimeSpanPicker.